# What's the meaning of もらたらす?

Tags: translation, meaning

It appears in contexts like:

1. [the title of this post: あなたに自由をもらたらすもの・・・](http://ameblo.jp/sonyidei/entry-11240835476.html)
2. [the text 灰色の中で輝きと落ち着きをもらたらす here](http://mixi.jp/view_bbs.pl?comm_id=3827706&id=36956970)
3. [禍をもらたらす鱗 here](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/namemillia/e/bf6d5f1e2c7f47422cbb21c746e1c680)

I tried many dictionaries and translation engines, but there's no match (not even an approximation).

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be a typo for 「**もたらす**」, which means "to bring", "to cause", "to produce", etc.

Comment: I would have thought so, but it's too widespread for that, appearing even in official sites and proofread contexts. Also, some of the axamples of usage that I've come accross with make no sense with that meaning.

Comment: @Kemm もたらす makes perfect sense in the three examples you linked. Can you edit your question to add some examples of "もらたらす" where replacing it with もたらす _wouldn't_ make sense?

Comment: After searching a bit more, it may be, though maybe a variant instead of a typo (or so I am made to believe seeing that [http://www.sgec-eco.org/aboutsgec/junkan.html this page] has もらたらす at the title but もたらす at the main body).

If so, then [http://www.kakehashi.or.jp/?p=4906 this article's title] would read as "The exclusion zone of 80km around Fukushima causes death"? Because it's sentences like that what make me doubt...

Comment: @Kemm It's not really widespread.  [Google Japanese web n-gram](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2009T08) counts: もたらす 2554308 versus もらたらす 243.

Comment: @Kemm That Fukushima website in general has some strange Japanese.  I don't think Japanese is his/her first language. At any rate, that website is not one I would use to study Japanese; I'd stick with major news websites.